# IE8 ActiveX control issue from intranet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, activex

I have some static pages ,working perfectly in all browsers(ie8,ie9,Mozilla,chrome,safari).
When I open the static pages in ie8,It prompt to allow for ActiveX control,If I do not allow the ActiveX control, the pages are  not displaying perfectly ,If I allow the ActiveX control the pages  work fine.

My problem is,When i deploy the pages in a server(WCS) in an intranet, If i access the URL from **IE8** it does not prompt for ActiveX control ,so it  does not allow that ActiveX control and does not  display as expected but the pages are  working perfectly in other browsers (ie9,Mozilla,chrome,safari).

Please advice me how can i overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**html5shiv-printshiv.js**

This includes all of the above, as well as a mechanism allowing HTML5 elements to be styled and contain children while being printed in IE 6-8.

[Download link](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv)